# Oozie Behavior with misaligned start

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I noticed that if I start an Oozie coordinator with a start time many "iterations" (in terms of the frequency) previous to the current time, then the coordinator would sequentially run workflows several times, ignoring the assigned frequency. However, for me it is more important that the workflow/action run itself at the assigned frequency, than it is for workflow/action to have run the correct number of times at a given point.

Is there any way I can avoid this behavior? One way would obviously be to ensure the start time is correct within an iteration time (is there a way to have it automatically take the start time?). Another would be to configure it to avoid this behavior altogether, and basically run at the next time when it should have given the start time and the frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious way to avoid side effects from "past" start dates is... to set the actual start date at submission time as "now".

That's the way we do it in my team:

- on the local filesystem, write down a "Coord-template.xml" with a
  placeholder such as *start="%Now%"*
- just before submitting, generate the actual "Coordinator.xml" with

  sed "s/%Now%/$(date --utc '+%FT%TZ')/" coord-template.xml > coordinator.xml
- upload the coordinator definition to HDFS then submit it via Oozie CLI

~~~~~~~~~~~~

Aternative: if you are using "basic" frequency *(not CRON-like scheduling)* you may want to try these <controls> to have Oozie create executions for all "past" time slots but discard them immediately :

```
  <throttle>1</throttle>
```

and/or

```
  <execution>LAST_ONLY</execution>
```

[cf. Oozie 4.x reference](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.3._Synchronous_Coordinator_Application_Definition)

The rules would also apply in case the Coordinator is suspended then resumed, or in case the Oozie service gets stopped then restarted, or in case YARN has to queue new jobs for a really long time (because the cluster is 100% busy).

Answer (score 0):

Oozie has improved of late, so there's an easier solution available than the currently accepted answer.  As of Oozie 4.1, there is a "NONE" execution available.  This skips iterations which occur in the past, more or less.  Here's the doc snippet:

> NONE: Similar to LAST_ONLY except all older materializations are skipped. When NONE is set, an action that is WAITING or READY will be SKIPPED when the current time is more than a certain configured number of minutes (tolerance) past the action's nominal time. By default, the threshold is 1 minute. For example, suppose action 1 and 2 are both WAITING , the current time is 5:20pm, and both actions' nominal times are before 5:19pm. Both actions will become SKIPPED, assuming they don't transition to SUBMITTED (or a terminal state) before then. Another way of thinking about this is to view it as similar to setting the timeout equal to 1 minute which is the smallest time unit, except that the SKIPPED status doesn't cause the coordinator job to eventually become DONEWITHERROR and can actually become SUCCEEDED (i.e. it's a "good" version of TIMEDOUT ).

[Oozie 4.1 doc](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.3._Synchronous_Coordinator_Application_Definition)

I have tested this, and it does work with CRON frequencies.  It is superior to the LAST_ONLY execution in your case because LAST_ONLY will still run the most recent iteration in the past (with the misaligned time), in addition to current/future iterations.

```
<execution>NONE</execution>
```